# Google Chrome Extension error - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4567/save. Origin chrome-extension://cbemaelkkmebiohhjgmlclegalijdbbh is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Even thought I'm getting this error the extension seems to be calling the URL. The message passing from contentscript.js to background.html took me a few minutes to wire up, but seems ok. I'm confused.

Here is my manifest.

```
{
  "name": "FirstExt",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My First Extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*"],
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"]
  }
  ],
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [ "http://*", 
               "http://localhost:4567/*" ]
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm not really using the popup.html for anything yet. Its empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing http://* to http://*/ (and removing the localhost entry).

If you're trying to access a https page, you will need that too.

Answer (score 8):

Replace `"http://*"` with `"<all_urls>"`.

Comment: Do you need to remove this before uploading the extension?